# Use A6000 as webcam type camera

Tags: live, output

I need to do a live stream and I'm looking for a way to connect my Sony A6000 to my computer so that it can be used as a camera for Facebook Live. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real time output you only have hdmi (the USB is for file transfer) so all you need is an hdmi input card for your PC.

Then you can grab that input as a source for applications.